# How send value of no-captcha (v2) to another page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, recaptcha

How send value of recaptcha to another page with jQuery?

```
<head>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
...

<form>
<div class="g-recaptcha"  data-size="normal" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
<input type="sumbit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$.post('index.php', { 
     hiddenRecaptcha: grecaptcha.getResponse(),
...
```

I also try:

```
hiddenRecaptcha: $("#g-recaptcha-response").val(),
```

Answer (score 0):

read from [official reference](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) ; there are 3 ways  but here you are sending with javascript so make below changes in your form

**PS:** remember the script order otherwise you will not get the recaptcha

assign a unique id to your div of recaptcha

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="my-recaptcha" data-size="normal"></div>
```

now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var my_recaptcha_widget;
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        if($('#my-recaptcha').length) {
            my_recaptcha_widget = grecaptcha.render('my-recaptcha', {
              'sitekey' : '6LfbhhQTAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXCJlFajw'
            });
        }
 };      
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

in

```
$.post({'whatever.php',{ 'recaptcha' : recaptcha.getResponse(my_recaptcha_widget)}
});
```